# CLLocation + Weather(Alamofire) issues

Tags: swift, alamofire, cllocation

I am trying to use CLLocation to capture longitude and latitude and then use the longitude and latitude in Alamofire to get weather. Every time, the longitude and latitude won't stop updating and the weather data won't print(if you wanna check it out here's an example link of the data: http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=37.33233141&lon=-122.0312186&FcstType=json)

```
class SampleViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
var startLocation: CLLocation!
var isFetchingWeather = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   }

     override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            getCurrentLocation()
     }
   func getCurrentLocation(){
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }
}

     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
        if isFetchingWeather != false{
    print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
    print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")
    let requestLink = "http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)&lon=\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)&FcstType=json"
    print(requestLink)
    Alamofire.request(requestLink).validate().responseJSON
        { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                let json = JSON(data)
                self.weatherData = json["data"].arrayValue
                    for weather in self.weatherData{
                    let temp = weather["weather"].stringValue
                       self.weatherString.append(temp)
                }
                print (self.weatherString)
                if self.startLocation == nil {
                    self.startLocation = userLocation as! CLLocation
                    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
                }


            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
        }
        else{
            print("is fetching weather is false")
        }

}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
{
    print("Error \(error)")
}
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't run your weather request inside your location delegate.  Instead, get your location in the `didUpdateLocations` delegate and save it to a var. Next, call `stopUpdatingLocation()` then call a separate function to make your weather request. Something like this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let newLocation = locations.last

//check accuracy and timestamp of location to make sure its not a cached/old location (if you don't care about accuracy or time, you can remove this check)
    let timeDiff = newLocation?.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow

    if timeDiff < 5.0 && (newLocation?.horizontalAccuracy)!<=self.accuracyNeeded{

        //stop updating location
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        //set currentUserLocation
        self.myLocation=newLocation?.coordinate


        //call function to get weather

        //remove delegate
        self.locationManager.delegate = nil

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks +1 ! just about everything is working-- even the link with the longitude and latitude is printing, but the alamofire itself is returning nothing... @rmp

Comment: is it possible that there is no weather data at that location? Or are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag to indicate when you start fetching weather info and do not call Alamofire to fetch weather information if that flag is set. For example, you would declare something like after the line where you declare `startLocation`:

```
var isFetchingWeather = false
```

Then, in `locationManagerdidUpdateLocations` first check if `isFetchingWeather` is false. If not, return. Otherwise, fetch the weather info.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if isFetchingWeather {
        return
    }
    isFetchingWeather = true
    // Do the actual weather fetching
}
```

Of course, you might want to do the actual fetching of the weather after you've gotten a few location updates since the initial ones might not be that accurate :)

Comment: i tried that and inside of the if statement for the else part i put a print saying that it was false. i ran the app and the console printed the print non-stop. @Fahim

Comment: Did you set `isFetchingWeather` to `true` the first time you executed the fetch? Can you provide a code sample so that I can see what you are doing? It's a bit difficult to know how your code executes without seeing it :)

Comment: Yeah-- sorry it took so long. No I didn't.   Let me just update the code in my question with the code I ran @Fahim .

Comment: In your updated code, you appear to fetch weather info only if `isFetchingWeather` is not `false` - meaning you have to be fetching weather to fetch weather info again :) That's not how it should work. See my updated code in my answer above as to how you should set it up.